How do I enable scrolling through a flow layout panel in Windows forms app?
I tried to find an answer and did not find anything. Please someone help, I'm desperate. Here is my full code of Form1 and the graphic design of Form1.
using LibraryDatabaseApp.Properties;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices;
using Mysqlx.Crud;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using static System.Reflection.Metadata.BlobBuilder;

namespace LibraryDatabaseApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        BindingSource bookBindingSource = new BindingSource();
        private Main_Form mainForm;
        public int bookCount = 24;

        public Form1(Main_Form mainForm)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.mainForm = mainForm;
            this.KeyPreview = true;
            this.KeyDown += Form1_KeyDown;

            // Enable FlowLayoutPanel scrolling
            flowLayoutPanel1.AutoScroll = true;

            // Attach event handlers
            flowLayoutPanel1.Scroll += FlowLayoutPanel1_Scroll;
            VScrollBar1.Scroll += VScrollBar1_Scroll;

            // Initialize scrollbar state
            UpdateScrollBar();
        }

        private void UpdateScrollBar()
        {
            // Get the total content height and the visible height
            int contentHeight = flowLayoutPanel1.DisplayRectangle.Height;
            int visibleHeight = flowLayoutPanel1.ClientSize.Height;

            if (contentHeight > visibleHeight) // If content is larger than the visible area
            {
                VScrollBar1.Enabled = true;

                // Configure scrollbar properties
                VScrollBar1.Minimum = 0;
                VScrollBar1.Maximum = contentHeight - visibleHeight;
                VScrollBar1.LargeChange = visibleHeight;
                VScrollBar1.SmallChange = 20;

                // Synchronize scrollbar with FlowLayoutPanel scroll position
                SafeSetScrollBarValue(VScrollBar1, -flowLayoutPanel1.AutoScrollPosition.Y);
            }
            else
            {
                VScrollBar1.Enabled = false; // Disable scrollbar if no scrolling is required
            }
        }

        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                button2_Click(sender, e);
            }
        }

        private Panel CreateBookPanel(Book book)
        {
            Panel bookPanel = new Panel
            {
                Width = 200,
                Height = 250,
                Margin = new Padding(10),
                BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
                Tag = book // Store the book object for easy retrieval
            };

            bookPanel.Click += BookPanel_Click;

            PictureBox coverPictureBox = new PictureBox
            {
                Width = 180,
                Height = 120,
                SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom,
                Dock = DockStyle.Top,
            };
            coverPictureBox.Load(book.ImageURL);
            coverPictureBox.Click += BookPanel_Click;

            Label titleLabel = new Label
            {
                Text = book.BookName,
                AutoSize = false,
                Width = bookPanel.Width,
                Height = 40,
                TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter,
                Dock = DockStyle.Top
            };
            titleLabel.Click += BookPanel_Click;

            Label authorLabel = new Label
            {
                Text = "Author: " + book.AuthorName,
                AutoSize = false,
                Width = bookPanel.Width,
                Height = 20,
                TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter,
                Dock = DockStyle.Top
            };
            authorLabel.Click += BookPanel_Click;

            bookPanel.Controls.Add(coverPictureBox);
            bookPanel.Controls.Add(titleLabel);
            bookPanel.Controls.Add(authorLabel);

            return bookPanel;
        }

        private void BookPanel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Panel clickedPanel = sender as Panel;
            if (clickedPanel == null && sender is Control control && control.Parent is Panel parentPanel)
            {
                clickedPanel = parentPanel;
            }

            if (clickedPanel != null && clickedPanel.Tag is Book selectedBook)
            {
                BookForm bookForm = new BookForm(
                    mainForm,
                    selectedBook.BookName,
                    selectedBook.AuthorName,
                    selectedBook.Year.ToString(),
                    selectedBook.ImageURL,
                    selectedBook.ISBN,
                    selectedBook.Description,
                    selectedBook.Language
                );

                mainForm.LoadForm(bookForm);
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BooksDAO booksDAO = new BooksDAO();
            List<Book> books = booksDAO.getAllBooks();

            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear();

            foreach (var book in books)
            {
                Panel bookPanel = CreateBookPanel(book);
                flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(bookPanel);
            }

            UpdateScrollBar(); // Update scrollbar after content changes
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BooksDAO booksDAO = new BooksDAO();
            string searchTerm = textBox1.Text;
            List<Book> searchResults = booksDAO.searchBooks(searchTerm);

            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear();

            foreach (var book in searchResults)
            {
                Panel bookPanel = CreateBookPanel(book);
                flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(bookPanel);
            }

            if (searchResults.Count == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No books found for the search term: " + searchTerm);
            }

            UpdateScrollBar(); // Update scrollbar after content changes
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            mainForm.LoadForm(new MenuForm(mainForm));
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            mainForm.LoadForm(new MenuForm(mainForm));
        }

        private void pictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            mainForm.LoadForm(new MenuForm(mainForm));
        }

        private void FlowLayoutPanel1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
        {
            SafeSetScrollBarValue(VScrollBar1, -flowLayoutPanel1.AutoScrollPosition.Y);
        }

        private void VScrollBar1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
        {
            flowLayoutPanel1.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(0, VScrollBar1.Value);
        }

        private void SafeSetScrollBarValue(VScrollBar scrollBar, int value)
        {
            if (scrollBar.Value != value)
            {
                if (value < scrollBar.Minimum)
                    scrollBar.Value = scrollBar.Minimum;
                else if (value > scrollBar.Maximum)
                    scrollBar.Value = scrollBar.Maximum;
                else
                    scrollBar.Value = value;
            }
        }
    }
} 

Form 1 graphic design
I tried chat gpt but it made it worse. I found some simple solutions on youtube, but they did not do anything. Could someone check my code please, I am really desperate.

"Here is my code, figure out what it does, then fix what it does wrong" - doesn't seems like you are desparate. You can remove first and last paragraph as they are and start with explaining the problem.

WHat do you mean by scrolling?
Like scrolling in the panels scrolling trough multiple panels?
It is easiest to use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol?view=windowsdesktop-8.0 rather than VScrollBar directly

Also: this question is not related to Visual Studio (the development environment), but to Winforms. I adjusted the tags accordingly.

You really need to explain why you have a ScrollBar Control there, given a FlowLayoutPanel can already present one on its own when auto-scrolling is enabled. Moreover, all those floating Controls that constitute a book should actually be a single UserControl (which would also solve the issue by itself)
